# Vue.js 500 error in Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Пишу проект на laravel + vue.js.
Вопрос в следующем: как в  vue отловить http ошибку с сервера? в моем случае, нужно отловить 500 error и сделать редирект на страницу об ошибке? пугает пользователей, когда 500 ошибка со стандартным выводом laravel No message

Comment: эта ошибка возникает при первом заходе на сайт или приходит с Ajax-ответом?

Comment: @Дмытрык возникало только при тайм аутах php и нехватке памяти, в общем, нужно сделать редирект если 500 ошибка по примеру 404 редиректа

Comment: ну так сделайте, у Вас же даже пример есть.

Comment: @Дмытрык я не пойму как это в vue router обработать, вот в чем вопрос